# Comparing values of arrays in C#

Tags: c#

I have a bool array that looks like this

```
bool[] responses = new bool[] {true, false, true};
```

And two classes that look like this:

```
public class Person {
  public IList<PersonDetail> PersonDetails
}

public class PersonDetail {
  public bool   Correct { get; set; }
}

PersonDetails
 >> PersonDetail[0].correct = true
 >> PersonDetail[1].correct = true
 >> PersonDetail[2].correct = false
```

Is there a simple way I can compare these to see if the true/false are equal for each? 
I was trying to use the c# `.SequenceEqual` but I don't know how to get the data from 
the PersonDetail class into a sequence xxx that I can use to compare with responses.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var equal = responses.Select(bool.Parse).SequenceEqual( xxx );
```

What I need to do is to compare the following:

```
responses[0] == PersonDetail[0].correct and
responses[1] == PersonDetail[1].correct and
responses[2] == PersonDetail[2].correct
```

So what's true in `responses[x]` should match true in `PersonDetail[x]` and what's false in `responses[x]` should match false in `PersonDetail[x]`

Comment: A lil bit confusing here. Do you want to compare if the Person array have a repeated items?

Comment: Surely this is for-loop territory, I don't see how linq could do anything but slow it down?

Comment: "*I have a string array that looks like this*"... nope, it's a bool array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure of your code, but maybe:

`var equal = responses.SequenceEqual(Person.PersonDetails.Select(PD => PD.correct);`

Comment: I added some more to the question. Hope it explains it better. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this will work because I have the class Person that contains PersonDetail classes in a list called PersonDetails. The flag I want to compare responses to is a field in the PersonDetail class.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. When I run your suggestion I get an error message saying: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property Person.PersonDetails.get

Comment: @czhili, Replace Person with the name of your Person variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't really clear, but I imagine you want to do the following:

```
var isEqual = responses.SequenceEqual(PersonDetail.Select(p=>p.Correct))
```

Comment: Cant the logical AND/OR operation be done, since they are bool type? I think thats much faster and efficient! :)

Comment: @zenwalker - I added some more to the question. Hope it explains it better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, this LINQ will do what you ask. I'm not sure it's more readable than a simple foreach loop but that's not the point!

```
public class Person 
{
  public IList<PersonDetail> PersonDetails;
}

public class PersonDetail 
{
  public bool   Correct;
}

void Main()
{
    bool[] responses = new bool[] {true, false, true};
    Person p = new Person();
    p.PersonDetails = new List<PersonDetail>();
    p.PersonDetails.Add(new PersonDetail(){Correct = true});
    p.PersonDetails.Add(new PersonDetail(){Correct = true});
    p.PersonDetails.Add(new PersonDetail(){Correct = false});

    //bool allGood = p.PersonDetails.Select((pd, index) => pd.Correct == responses[index]).All(x => x==true);

    bool allGood = responses.SequenceEqual(p.PersonDetails.Select(x => x.Correct));
    allGood.Dump(); // LINQpad extension
}
```

*[edit - OK, so it's early and I forgot about SequenceEquals which does the same thing in a much more readable manner. Code changed to match what everyone else already answered...].*

Comment: It's all relative - I'm not sure the LINQ is more readable than a for loop (if you don't know LINQ anyway) but the second LINQ is more readable than the first!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SequenceEqual like this

```
var responses = new [] { true, false, true };
var details = new List<PersonDetail>()
                { new PersonDetail() {Correct = true},
                  new PersonDetail() {Correct = false},
                  new PersonDetail() {Correct = true} };
var person = new Person() { PersonDetails = details };

var equal = responses.SequenceEqual(person.PersonDetails.Select(pd => pd.Correct));
```

Answer (score 1):

From the answers already given I've had a play around and come up with the below, seems to work - note that I'm also new to C# so this has been an interesting problem.

As JonB points out in one of the answers - what happens if the lengths of "responses" and "people" are different... Hope the below helps

```
class Program
{       
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool[] responses = new bool[] { true, false, true };

        Person people = new Person();
        people.PersonDetails.Add(new PersonDetail() { Correct = true });
        people.PersonDetails.Add(new PersonDetail() { Correct = false });
        people.PersonDetails.Add(new PersonDetail() { Correct = true });

        bool equal = responses.SequenceEqual(people.PersonDetails.Select(P=> P.Correct));
        Console.WriteLine (equal);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public List<PersonDetail> PersonDetails = new List<PersonDetail>();
}

public class PersonDetail
{
    public bool Correct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XOR and not AND or OR operations on these items. XOR table will give you 0 if both items are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't get much simpler than:-

```
  if (person.PersonDetails.Count != responses.Length)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Arrays are different lengths");
  bool result = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < person.PersonDetails.Count; i++)
  {
    if (person.PersonDetails[i].Correct != responses[i])
    {
      result = false;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Every programmer on the planet will be able to read it, even if they've never seen c#.

Actually it highlights a missing aspect of the spec; What should happen if the lists are different lengths?

Comment: If `responses` is shorter than `person.PersonDetails` however, you will get an error, so it does not address that aspect of the spec.

Comment: I'm not sure that "fancy" is really an objective in programming. There's a tendency towards spectacular flourishes when we're really after something that finishes quickly and can be read by a dog.

Comment: @Patrick I did mention that it highlights a missing aspect of the spec. Whilst it could return a value, should that be true or false? Since we don't know an error is valid.

Comment: Checked this out and it works. I think there is probably a one liner answer some place but this one does work :-)   responses and person.PersonDetails are always the same length.

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought that you meant it addressed that aspect. It definitely raises the question, as `SequenceEqual` will just return `false`

Comment: Of course my solution is still wrong if PersonDetails is shorter than responses, it'll return true if what it has matches. If they're expected to be the same, I guess it should check they are or throw before entering the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this:

```
IEnumerable<bool> answers = from x in Person.PersonDetails select x.correct;
bool equal = responses.SequenceEqual(answers)
```